# How to configure two IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 server to one IBM http web server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, server-configuration

Please help me in configuring two IBM MObilefirst Platform 7.1 ap server to one IBM HTTP Web server. As per the IBM Documents I should follow Server Farm configurations.
Need guidance in doing the same.
**Scenario 1**
Resources: Two App Servers with IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 installed and plugin-cfg geneated using jConsole. Each app server is having separate DB for each. One web server with IBM HTTP installed.
**Scenario 2**Resources: Two App Servers with IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 installed and plugin-cfg geneated using jConsole. Both the app server is having common DB. One web server with IBM HTTP installed.

I need both the app servers to be up at the same time in the above given scenarios. Please let me know in scenario one should I install any separate plugin for setting up server farm configuration.
note:In Scenario 2 currently only one App server can be made up at a time

Comment: You seem to know what to do - generating the plugin-cfg using jConsole. What is it that you are looking for? How to configure IHS with plugin-cfg.xml?

Comment: what about for Scenario 2?
can I run two servers at the same time with common database.

Comment: Of course, that is what MFP Farm is all about. This will be called symmetric deployment. Refer to :https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_server_farm_setup.html

Comment: what if the runtimes in both the app servers are different?For Instance one will be having runtimeUATand the other will be having runtimeE2E.

Comment: Every runtime needs its own DB. Two different runtimes cannot share the same DB. You will need different schemas/DBs

Comment: OK Thanks for your clarification regarding the DB and runtime. So if am planning to use different schemas for each app server then theres no need of server farm topology , right? Which one should I use? Is it standalone?

Comment: Each runtime needs it own DB. The concept of Farm or WAS cluster deployment is to have the same runtime(s) across different JVMs to provide load balancing and scalability. In this case, the admin will be common and there will be multiple runtimes. Refer to documentation for more details

Answer (score 1):

Use JConsole to generate the plugin-cfg.xml from your individual Liberty servers. You can either merge the plugin-cfg.xml files manually or use Job Manager to generate a merged plugin from both the Liberty servers.

More details here:

[Setting up HTTP Server in a WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile farm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_liberty_8_5_cluster_env.html)

- Manually merge the files by using a text editor.
- Use the job manager to submit a Generate merged plugin configuration for Liberty servers job.

[Generating a merged plug-in configuration for Liberty profile servers using the job manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tagt_jobmgr_liberty_plugin_merge.html?view=embed)